# UIScrollView event handling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make my own custom `UIScrollView` for some reason. The question is, is it possible to exactly mimic the event handling behavior of `UIScrollView` including 'delayed content touches' and 'cancellable content touches'? That is, the custom scroll view should delay handling the event until it can determine if scrolling is the intent, and it should also be able to cancel its subviews' touches later. The problem is as follows:

1) hitTest: should return immediately so I can't delay the determination of the touch owner.
2) We can't cancel a touch event later programmatically. There's no such api.
3) I tried to override the `sendEvent:` method, but it didn't help. Having to call `[super sendEvent:]` will send events to unintended views. Moreover, hit test has been already done when `sendEvent:` was called and we can't alter the value of `UITouch.view` later.

So again the question is, is it possible to make a custom `UIScrollView` including it's touch handling behavior without using `UIScrollView`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The real question is:  it is worth the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that the gestureRecognizers (Pan and Zoom) that are used for regular UIScrollViews are private properties until iOS 5.0 comes out. I suppose when they are public you could transfer them to your own scroll view.